# Making a table dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Made a table for a product listings page that has a row of 3 images, then a row of text below each image, then repeat.  Rather than have the page scroll down indefinitely, I figure it would be better to use some JS/jQuery to change the values in each < td > (img & matching text) than to create a new page for every 6 products. However, my kindergarten-level JS is failing me miserably.

While I think the question I'm asking above is pretty obvious, I'm also wondering if this never should have been set up as a table in the first place.  It seemed like the easiest way to keep it organized, but the few examples I've seen seem to do this with < div >'s rather than tables.

Here's a JSFiddle I was messing around with: http://jsfiddle.net/jshweky/FgVY2/

HTML:

```
<table id="saladGrid">
    <tr class="saladPics">
        <td class="s1"></td>
        <td class="s2"></td>
        <td class="s3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="saladTxt">
        <td class="txt">
            <p>acorn squash, golden beets, pistachios</p>
        </td>
        <td class="txt">
            <p>roasted eggplant, herbed ricotta, sumac</p>
        </td>
        <td class="txt">
            <p>arugula, fennel, blackberries, quinoa, pickled shallots</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="saladPics">
        <td class="s4"></td>
        <td class="s5"></td>
        <td class="s6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="saladText">
        <td class="text">
            <p>arugula, orange, golden beets, golden tomatoes, pistachios</p>
        </td>
        <td class="text">
            <p>caesar</p>
        </td>
        <td class="text">
            <p>butternut squash, lime, feta, chili</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS (paraphrased):

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#saladGrid table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-spacing: 30px;
}
.saladPics td {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 415px 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 250px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.saladText {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
.saladPics td.s1 {
    background-image: url("http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a514/jshweky/Gourmade%20to%20Order/IMG_1989_zps38d802a7.jpg");
}
```

I figure it's a matter of creating new var's and writing a function to add 6 to the existing img class (e.g. s1 becomes s7, etc.) but that's just a guess and as I said, even if that's right I'm still in the embryonic stages of JS coding.

Comment: the fiddle is empty, is this a joking?

Comment: you need bootstrap in your life my friend

Comment: Fiddle wasn't empty when I saved it.  Strange.  Also, I'm trying to learn the languages before I get into frameworks so I have a more thorough understanding of them, but I do plan on getting into bootstrap once I get comfortable with hand coding CSS.  But I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript to Swap the image works fine, the issue is the first part of your script. I commented it out in the fiddle and it worked fine. There are definitely better ways to do this (sliding DIVs inside a container, build elements in javascript and append them to the frames on the page - this would give you almost a pinterest style effect of loading new elements at the bottom) - it all depends on how you want to handle it but my suggestion would be to look into using jQuery to add or remove elements to the DOM.

```
//var s7= new image();
//img.src=url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHC9Vk1U5yC5RWMhUK9Ai2RGIDCSh-wxPt-aleQm9onxi9xbN9dA');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        $('.s1').css('background-image', 'url("http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a514/jshweky/Gourmade%20to%20Order/IMG_1483_zpsc4ca87cf.jpg")');
    });
});
```

Also, here is an alternate syntax for the .css() that will let you change more than one property of an elements at a time (you will need to use the .html() function to change the text in the following element too):

```
$('.s1').css({backgroundImage : 'url("http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a514/jshweky/Gourmade%20to%20Order/IMG_1483_zpsc4ca87cf.jpg")', backgroundSize : "cover"}); });
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that was actually a miscommunication on my part.  I had started setting up the second page of images as new variables, which is what the first 2 lines of code you commented out were for, but then I realized I had no idea what I was doing so I just stopped.  I'm actually looking for a way to make all 6 images, with matching text, to transform/slide to 6 new images and matching text.  Basically making a page 2 without actually having to load a new page in the browser.  So I would imagine there's one function I could write to do it all in one shot, no?

Comment: Here is a really simple jquery animation that moves between pages without reloading the pages (essentially it is a slider for html elements instead of images). [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/Y6rgc/) - hopefully this is more on par with the bahavior you had in mind